# Error message 'Can't write to textfile: File is being used by another process'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file

I have one problem with my C# form. I have a textbox, used to add the content when I click on a button to an external txt file and a combobox which displays the txt file content.

**My code:**

```
String PathFile = @"Mypath";

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(PathFile);
    sw.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
    sw.Close();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(PathFile);
        string line = sr.ReadLine();
        while (line != null)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(line);
            line = sr.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

The combobox works great and displays the content, but when I try to add a new entry with the textbox, the result is the following.

> system.io.ioexception the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

I understand that the file is locked by the process for the combobox, but what can I do to resolve this situation?

Comment: well it cut the greating at the first line, sorry, and Hi guys !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are not disposing of the `StreamReader` during your form load.

```
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(PathFile))
{
    string line = sr.ReadLine();
    while (line != null)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(line);
        line = sr.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Also, when you're using the `StreamWriter` to write data to the file, you also need to dispose of the stream:

```
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(PathFile))
{ 
    sw.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
}
```

So what does `using` do?  It's quite a neat construct.  It takes an `IDisposable` and ensures that the object is disposed whether the code reaches the end of the `using` block, or an exception is thrown.  We need to dispose of things like streams because they hold unmanaged resources (e.g. file handles), and we don't want to wait for the garbage collector to kick in and actually free the handle.

`using` is semantically equivalent to:

```
IDisposable someObjectThatIsDispoable; // e.g. StreamWriter/StreamReader, et al
try
{
     // your code here
}
finally
{
    if(someObjectThatIsDisposable != null)
        someObjectThatIsDisposable.Dispose();
}
```

Also, dispose takes care of closing the file, so the call to `Close` is unnecessary (hence they have been removed from this answer).

Comment: `"Also, when you're writing, do this - it also needs disposing."` Can you please explain?

Comment: This post gives a correct answer, but could use some more explanation of what exactly `using` is for, and how it works.

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to open/close a Stream is through the [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

In your Form_Load

```
 using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(PathFile))
 {
    string line = sr.ReadLine();
    while (line != null)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(line);
        line = sr.ReadLine();
    }
 }
```

This will ensure the proper closing and disposing of the StreamReader at the closing braces also in case of exceptions inside the using block

Of course, you should change in the same way also the Button_Click code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(PathFile))
    {
         sw.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
    }
    // No really needed to call close
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the other answers, you're getting that error because your stream is not being closed. However, you can avoid explicitly using a `StreamReader` and also shorten your code by using [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx) instead.

```
try
{
    foreach(string line in File.ReadAllLines(PathFile))
    {
       comboBox1.Items.Add(line);           
    }

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.Message);
}
```

Although not always necessarily, it's often a good idea to use a `using` block when dealing with classes that implement `IDisposable`. So for your `StreamWriter`, you could use this

```
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(PathFile))
{
   sw.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
}
```

This ensures that the stream is closed and the `StreamWriter` object is disposed.

Answer (score 1):

Release file by calling dispose on `StreamWriter` of load method.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(PathFile);
    try
    {
        string line = sr.ReadLine();
        while (line != null)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(line);
            line = sr.ReadLine();
        }
        sr.Dispose();
        sr = null; 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.Message);
    }
    finally //Just in case any exception is thrown.
    {
       if (sr != null)
           sr.Dispose();
           sr = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: The point of `using` is that it Disposes the object, even if an exception is thrown making this solution really unnecessarily long-winded, imho. :)

Comment: @Moo-Juice:Yeah I know what you are saying, but I am making a point to  OP so that he/she understand that there is an another way of doing this.

Comment: `Why not just wrap that code around a using` and you will not have to explicitly call `Dispose()`?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't dispose the `StreamReader`. Try this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StreamReader sr = null; // declare the StreamReader outside the try-catch-finally block
    try
    {

        sr = new StreamReader(PathFile);
        string line = sr.ReadLine();
        while (line != null)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(line);
            line = sr.ReadLine();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (sr != null)
        {
             sr.Dispose(); // dispose the StreamReader if it's not null
        }
    }
}
```